# thymeleaf and maven web project don't recognize css files

Tags: java, maven, thymeleaf, java-ee-7, tomcat9

I'm trying to link css files to an html file like they do in the next tutorial https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html but when I run the application in tomcat the HTML works but the CSS is missing and I get the next error on the browser console "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()", contrary to this if I open the html without tomcat the css file works fine, so I'm pointing to the file correctly.
If it helps I've created the project with maven-archetype-webapp

Here is my project structure

[image]

HTML where I want to link the css file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Web de productos - Inicias sesion</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
         href="../../css/normalize.css" th:href="@{/css/normalize.css}" />  
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all"
        href="../../css/index.css" th:href="@{/css/index.css}" />   
</head>
<body> ... </body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>ss.webdeproductos</groupId>
  <artifactId>WebDeProductos2</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>WebDeProductos2 Maven Webapp</name>
  <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
  <url>http://www.example.com</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
        
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>       
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.21</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>WebDeProductos2</finalName>
    <pluginManagement><!-- lock down plugins versions to avoid using Maven defaults (may be moved to parent pom) -->
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <!-- see http://maven.apache.org/ref/current/maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_war_packaging -->
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.0</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.1</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.2.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.5.2</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: When you are calling the running application, do you see the html? It is unclear to me, if nothing works or only the CSS is missing.

Comment: @ElmarBrauch Only the CSS is missing, I'm going to edit my question

Comment: I added one more aspect to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

There is a double definition of `href` in your thymeleaf templates, see `href="../../css/normalize.css" th:href="@{/css/normalize.css}"`. You should remove one of those - check your html sources in browser the path will probably not match to your folder structure.

Thymeleaf has a different base location to check for static files like css (or js).
Since you are referencing css file this way `th:href="@{/css/normalize.css}"` try this folder structure:

- WEB-INF/static
- WEB-INF/static/css
- WEB-INF/static/js
- WEB-INF/templates

In my German blog I wrote an article about Spring Boot and Thymeleaf:
https://agile-coding.blogspot.com/2020/10/spring-mvc-thymeleaf.html

My sample code including the folder structure can be found here:
https://github.com/elmar-brauch/thymeleaf

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I tried this folder structure but it doesn't work. I think that kind of folder structure works when you are using spring but I'm not using Spring. Anyways if I can't solve this problem i'm going to move my project to spring where I know that this works fine.

Comment: I've tried like you say but that hasn't worked. I think that the problem is elsewhere becuase if you see the tutorial that I leave in the question they use a folder structure like mine (here is the project https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleafexamples-gtvg is from the thymeleaf official page).